# Retrieving VB6 working directory from Addin

Tags: vb6

I googled a lot and also used regedit on my machine, but to avail,
so I'm asking it here :

I need to retrieve the value of VB6.exe working directory from a Visual Basic 6 Addin (by code).

If I remember well, this is the same directory of the executable by default
(**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\"** on my machine (Windows 7 Pro 64 bit))
but it can be changed right clicking the VB6.exe shortcut and typing the desired value in
the 'Start in' field.

Apparently, there is no way to retrieve it from the **VBE** class ( or any other class in the **VBIDE**, for that matter).

I guess the only solution is reading it from the windows registry, but which is the proper key ?

I searched it in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Visual Basic* , where the TabWidth setting for the IDE editor is saved, and in many other places.
I also made a full registry search : no luck.

Anybody can give me a hint ?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the delay, but I spent some time to test this thing.

First thing, I apologize : I jumped to conclusions too soon.

At a first try, rene's code worked and CurDir did not.
After some tests, both worked or failed , apparently at random.
To discover what was wrong, I created a VB6 addin that uses *CurDir*, *GetCurrentDirectory* only,
and both *GetCurrentProcess* and *GetCurrentDirectory* to retrieve the current directory.

It logs to a file the above values adding App.Path and whether it is running in VB IDE or 
as a compiled DLL.

I then copied the addin project folder in various places, launched each in IDE mode and then compiled.

I won't bother you including the full log file .
Please take my word that all three approaches return *always* the same value.

To be short, it turns out that the returned value(s) depend on the addin project 
directory location.

If the directory is under the parent path of VB working directory,
it returns the proper value either in IDE or compiled mode.

In the other case, it returns App.Path when running in the IDE;
if compiled, though, it returns the proper value.

We can say that *rene*'s and *D.Ddgg*'s solutions are equivalent in this case.
I thank both for their help, but the problem remains.

@ D.Ddgg :

> The directory at the end of the active path is called the current
>   directory;  it is the directory in which the active application
>   started, unless explicitly changed.  An application can determine
>   which directory is current by calling the GetCurrentDirectory
>   function.

It looks like the active path changes depending on the running mode.
What do you think about that ?
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Might be harcode but can't you do a [GetCurrentProcess](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=431) and then [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: VB has curdir function. Things like this have nothing to do with the registry.

Comment: I just tried that and it works like a charm!

Comment: @D.Ddgg : first thing I tried. It returns the current directory of the **addin** itself, not that of the calling Visual Basic Instance.

Comment: @rene : if you answer, I'll upvote you.  If I answer myself, I guess I can't .

Comment: In the comment above I meant I tried rene's advice.

Comment: I  can't provide a working sample so I rather not convert my comment to an answer. I did found some additional stuff: http://vb.mvps.org/samples/CmdLine/   feel free to post an answer and accept it...

Comment: Current Directory is a per process thing. Addins don't have one. They use whatever is the process is using. `The directory at the end of the active path is called the current directory; it is the directory in which the active application started, unless explicitly changed. An application can determine which directory is current by calling the GetCurrentDirectory function.

`

Comment: I updated the question after some testing.

Comment: Here's the CurDir command in WinDbg showing it just calls GetCurrentDirectoryA (ANSI version). `0012fa54 7278b5ac 00000104 0012fa78 0015f560 kernel32!GetCurrentDirectoryA`.

Comment: Thus calling *GetCurrentProcess* is pointless, because there is only one process,  
and calling *GetCurrentDirectory* is overkill, because *CurDir* already calls it. 
Evidently Visual Basic interpreter and compiler behave differently in this scenario.